# Basis of an eigenspace with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand how to find basis of an eigenspace. But currently it confuses me when I get complex eigenvalues.
I have this matrix:
$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}  $

Then I calculated:

$\lambda _{1}=1, \lambda _{2}=1+i, \lambda _{3}=1-i$

Then, for example for the second eigenvalue I did this:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 1+i & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1+i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1+i  \end{pmatrix}  $

And got this system:

$x_{1}i+x_{2}-x_{3}=0$

$-x_{2}i=0$

$x_{1}-x_{3}i=0$

So I got all 0. Is it possible that basis vector is (0,0,0) or I am making mistake somewhere.

Comment: You have a typo ( or a mistake) in the first equation of the system: it must be: $-x_1i+x_2-x_3=0$

Answer (score 1):

**No,** $(0,0,0)$ is never an eigenvector or basis element!

We indeed get $x_2=0$ from the equation in middle, but then the other two equations should state the same in an eigenvalue problem.

Now you had a sign mistake in the first equation, first coefficient should be $-i$: thus both this and the third line would mean
$$x_1=x_3i\,.$$
So that e.g. $(i,0,1)$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: Yes I made mistake in calculation. But now I am not sure how to solve this system. Because I got 2 equations that are opposite.
$-x_{1}i-x_{3}=0  $ 

$x_{1}i+x_{3}=0  $

Comment: Just ignore one of them and set arbitrarily one of the variables (e.g. to 1), which will set the other one as well.